# Linq for NHibernate and fetch mode of eager loading

Tags: linq, nhibernate, fetch, eager

Is there a way to set the fetchmode to eager for more than one object using linq for nhibernate. There seems to be an expand method which only allows me to set one object. However I need to set it for more than one object. Is this possible? Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

just use it more then once.

```
IList<Entity> GetDataFromDatabase()
{
    var query = session.Linq<Entity>();
    query.Expand("Property1");
    query.Expand("Property2");
    return query.ToList();
}
```

Comment: or query.Expand("Property1,Property2");

Comment: Is that an expansion method? Can't find it in NHibernate.Linq v2.0.50727.

Comment: It is there, on NHibernate.Linq.Query<T>

Answer (score 106):

The new Linq provider does it a little differently:

```
var customers = session.Query<Customer>().Fetch(c => c.Orders).ToList();
```

More here:
http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2010/08/nhibernate-linq-eager-fetching.html

Comment: if `Orders` has a sub class of its own, would it load eagerly? if not - how would you change the query to load it?

Comment: To get grandchilds: `var customers = session.Query<Customer>()
    .FetchMany(c => c.Orders)
    .ThenFetchMany(o => o.OrderLines).ToList();`

Answer (score 8):

As far as I can see, this is not equivalent: SetFetchMode hydrates an objects tree and the Expand method retrieves a cartesian product.

Answer (score 1):

In contiune to `@Mike Hadlow` answer, fetching next level (grandchildren) you need to do:

`var customers = session.Query<Customer>()
    .FetchMany(c => c.Orders)
    .ThenFetchMany(o => o.OrderLines).ToList();`